# I'm trying to get best calculation of Sub total VAT and Total

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, math, datagridview

[image]I'm trying to get best calculation of Sub total, VAT percentage and Total but I dont know what I missed here. the right calculation as I know for amount 100 and vat 15% is: subtotal = 86.96 and vat = 13.04 and total = 100 when VAT included.
But my code giving me another result. So what is the correct code and what I missed?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

    {
        row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Amount"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Qtty"].Index].Value) * 
            Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["PurchasePrice"].Index].Value));
    }

    //datagridview column total in label
    decimal sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

    {
        sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    }
    lblSum.Text = sum.ToString();

    //vat
    decimal vat = (sum * 15 / 100);
    lblVat.Text = vat.ToString();

    //subtotal 
    decimal subtotal = (sum - vat);
    lblSubtotal.Text = subtotal.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you show current bad result?

Comment: 15% of 100 is 15, how do you get 13.04?

Comment: In Russia from July 2020, the VAT is 15% and reduced VAT is 13.04%. Maybe you have products with different VAT rate. The joy of accounting.

Comment: Probably 100 is the price including VAT, 86.96 is the net value to which you add 15% to get 100

Comment: @Steve when I doing 2 operations in the invoice with (purchase amount 100) and filing 2 rows of datagridview with items, when I press the button the field of vat amount in db = 26.087 for TWO records as a bulk, and this is wrong because it's taken the value from lblvat.text while the correct result should be for each record in db = 1st record is 13.04 of vat and 2nd record is 13.04 of vat. separated with each other in db. so, the problem in the SQL command or code? I have issue with inserting the query
com.CommandText = "insert into Operations (VATIn) values ( '" + lblVat.t + ")";

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question detailing the problem in the question itself with the actual code (including the part that insert the value in the database). Anyway, remember that concatenating strings to form an sql query is prone to many errors like the database misunderstanding the decimal separator. (and I don't event talk about sql injection). Please use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to obtain the VAT separation from a sum that contains the price including VAT then you should change this line

```
decimal vat = (sum * 15 / 100);
```

to

```
decimal vatpct = 15m;
decimal vat = Math.Round(sum - (sum / (1 + ( vatpct / 100))),2);
```

or simplyfied a bit

```
decimal vatpct = 1 + (100 / 15m);
decimal vat = sum - Math.Round((sum / vatpct),2);
```

Of course remember to load that 15 constant from some configuration because this value changes too often.

Comment: thanks, bro, could you explain "Of course remember to load that 15 constant from some configuration because this value changes too often."

Comment: Usually governments like to fiddle with this value depending on how they think the economy will perform and how much money they need. Having the constant inside the code will force you to recompile and redistribute. While, if you read it from some configuration medium (file, db), you could just change the value externally.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm going to add another column in the same datagrideview called items. what I want to do is when I put on any item into that field automatically got the id of that item from SQL database on label or texbox
so, my skills in c# not enough and you may give help

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question. In this way more people will look at your question and you can get more help. Beside it is not well accepted in this site to change a question after it has been answered.

Comment: I have attemp with this code but not working

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            com.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            com.CommandText = "select ID from Items where Name = '"+ (row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns["Item"].Index].Value) + "' ";
            
        }

Comment: I added a new column for VAT and need to show every single row vat amount, could you help on that

Comment: Please post a new question with all the details required. More people can help you than just me

Comment: I can't post any new question!

Comment: do you think if I edit this post with a new one can this showing to all?
but I don't need to delete or edit it, it's reference for me. it has good info for me

Comment: No, changing the original question is very against the rules and it will be rolled back. If you have been banned to post new questions then you should wait the ban end